# What is the fastest compressing parameters for 7zip?

Tags: ubuntu, compression, 7-zip

My question is simple.

How can I fastest compressing via 7z?

I'm using this and It compresses a 2.5 gb file in about 4 minutes

```
    7z -a -r -t7z -mx1 -mmt=4
```

Is there any better option instead of -mx0 for faster compressing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compression is always a trade-off between the time it takes and the reduction that you can achieve.

The fastest compression is no compression.

`-mx` sets the compression level for a given algorithm.
You can look up valid levels depending on the algorithm here: https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/method.htm

Depending on the algorithm, setting it to `0` will disable compression. That's fast, but might not be, what you want.

You might want to try out different compression levels and algorithms to get the best trade-off between time and compression according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for help. But when I try to include some parameters from sevenzip manpage. I usually get invalid arg error, so I wanted to ask more experienced people here.